# generating/emailing reports on analysis update on sonarqube

Tags: report, sonarqube, teamcity, sonarqube-web

I am not able to find any plugin which can help in sending custom reports every time a sonar analysis. I see one PDF reports plugin which is paid. is there any free/opensource plugin to send email reports

Or is there a command line way to send email as part CI server(teamcity) build steps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attachments to email notifications are not currently supported in TeamCity. Please vote for the request: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-7318.